# How to remove git hooks

Tags: git, githooks

I had set up a git hook in pre-commit file to run `git pull` before any commit. Now I have deleted that file and restarted my computer multiple times, but that hook is still running before my commits.

How can I remove  or disable that completely?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I figured out what was causing that:
I had created my `pre-commit` hook in git core directory, but the git had created a pre-commit hook in project's `.git/hooks/` directory. I just removed it.

It means running the command that @romin21 mentioned inside project's root directory:

```
rm -rf .git/hooks
```

Comment: What about pushing this change to remote repo?

Comment: .git directory won't be pushed to remote. It just keeps info about repository in local.

Comment: My `.git/hooks` keeps show up even after I deleted it again and again, any advice?

Comment: @hxpax Let the directory be. Just delete its contents.

Comment: Run `rm -rf .git/hooks` in your project root directory.

Comment: thank you @romin21 for saving my day, this should be the correct answer

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. If you want to only temporarily disable the pre-commit hooks, you can just rename the `hooks` directory with `mv .git/hooks/ .git/hooks_bkup`, and rename it back after completing the commit action.

Answer (score 42):

Based on the documentation, git hooks should reside in `$GIT_DIR/hooks/` - verify this dir does not contain the `pre-commit` hook file

If the problem persists, you could flag your `git commit` with `--no-verify` (that should bypass the pre-commit hook)

Information can be found at:

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: Thanks roger. I had created ```pre-commit``` hook based on ```pre-commit.sample``` in ```$GIT_DIR/hooks/``` and then I removed it. I even searched for hook using ```locate pre-commit``` and there's nothing left, but it's running yet.

Comment: `--no-verify` is only partially helpful. If you want to do `git checkout` or wanna do `git rebase -i`, and those commits won't be allowed, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively there might be a path for `hooksPath` in your git config folder. You can open the config file in `.git/config` and remove or change the line starting with `hooksPath`.

Answer (score 4):

```
git config --unset core.hookspath
```